# toggle in javascript, change the default value

Tags: javascript

I want to put a hide/show text button on my website. The code I am using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(a){
var e=document.getElementById(a);
if(!e)return false;
if(e.style.display=="none"){
e.style.display="block"}
else{
e.style.display="none"}
return false;}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="return toggleMe('para1')" 
value="Show Abstract"><br>
<p id="para1">
<font color="#000000" size="2"><span style="line-height:24px">I study the sun. &nbsp;</span></font>
</p>
```

The result is successful and the button works, however by default it shows the text already, so the first click hides the text. I want the opposite, that the text is hidden and only appears when the user clicks.

Comment: Just add `style="display:none"` to the element that should be hidden.

Comment: Or use `Window.getComputedStyle()` to get `style` property of the element... `ELEMENT.style` will read only inline applied style..

Comment: just set display: none; initially?

Comment: The three answers sound intuitive, yet when implemented them none worked.

Comment: Works very well for me: https://jsfiddle.net/2ohjrguj/ .

Comment: Thanks a lot, I see it now!